# How to swap day by month in a Series with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-datetime

I have a column in which there are dates :

```
df['Date']

    Date
0 2020-25-04
1 2020-26-04
2 2020-27-04
3 2020-12-05
4 2020-06-05
Name: Date, Length: 5, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

I want to swap the element Day by element Month, so I can have :

```
df['Date']

     Date
0 2020-04-25
1 2020-04-26
2 2020-04-27
3 2020-05-12
4 2020-05-06
Name: Date, Length: 5, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to the output to be a string or do you want pandas in general to display dates in your custom format?

Comment: I want to display it in the datetime format, just as it is.

Comment: how did you end up with a datetime series like your input? as I can see the dtype is not object but datetime

Comment: it was like this : 25/04/2020 with type 'object'. and then, I converted it to datetime using this code : df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

Comment: can you try converting `pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],dayfirst=True)` as a first step?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':[np.datetime64('2020-04-25') ,np.datetime64('2020-04-26')]})

df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))

print(df)
```

I converted data into np.datetime format and applied lambda function.

Comment: It give a TypeError :TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Timestamp

Comment: @K.ossama I have edited the code. Try and let me know if it worked or not?